# Parent view not showing child view content in UIKit

Tags: swift, inheritance, uikit

I am trying to add a second UIViewController programmatically inside a main controller but i do not see any of its content in it all I see is a black screen. I am supposed to show a 8X8 board in the MainView so I added an instance of `BoardViewController()`

This The Child UIViewController where I already set the constraints in it

```
import UIKit

class BoardViewController: UIViewController {

    private let boardGame: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let board = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        board.allowsSelection =  true
        board.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return board
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(boardGame)
        
        boardGame.frame = view.bounds
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                
                boardGame.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                boardGame.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
                
               
                boardGame.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
                boardGame.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
                boardGame.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 16),
                boardGame.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)
            ])
        
       
        
        boardGame.delegate = self
        boardGame.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    init() {
           super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
       }
       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }
}

extension BoardViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 64
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "unique", for: indexPath)
              
              let chessRow = indexPath.row / 8
              if chessRow % 2 == 0 {
                  if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
                       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                  }else{
                      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                  }
              } else{
                  if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
                      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                  }else{
                      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                  }
              }
          
              return cell
          }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
           
           let width = collectionView.frame.size.width / 8.0
           let height = width
           return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
       }

}
```

and this is the Parent/main ViewController that receives the instance if it.

```
import UIKit

class MainView: UIViewController {

    let BoardView = BoardViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addBoardView()
    }
    
    func addBoardView(){
        addChild(BoardView)
        view.addSubview(BoardView.view)
        BoardView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

I already checked that the SceneDelegate is setup to receive the instance of `MainView()` and could not find any alert in XCODE  indicating there is any errors. Is there anything I might be missing?

```
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let window = UIWindow(frame: scene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainView())
        window.rootViewController = navVC
        self.window = window
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least 3 issues.

1. You need to create the `UIWindow` using the `scene`. Change:

   ```
   let window = UIWindow(frame: scene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
   ```
2. You never make the `window` the key window and visible. Add:

   ```
   window.makeKeyAndVisible()
   ```

   after setting its `rootViewController`.
3. Your `MainView` controller doesn't apply any constraints or set the frame of `BoardView.view`. Just after the call to:

   ```
   view.addSubview(BoardView.view)
   ```

   you need to either apply constraints to `BoardView.view` or you need to set the frame and autoresizingMask of `BoardView.view`.

---

Unrelated to your issue I'd like to point out your collection view constraints are redundant. If you are going to specify leading, trailing, top, and bottom, there is no reason to also specify the centerX and centerY constraints.

Your `MainView` class should be named `MainViewController` since it is a view controller and not just a view.

Your `BoardView` property should be named `boardView`. Class, struct, and enum names should start with uppercase. Variable, function, and case names should begin with lowercase.